# Protection against "CRIME attack"/Disable SSL compression under Ubuntu/Apache/2.2.22

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, compression

I'm trying to disable SSL compression in my server, but can't because SSLCompression option isn't yet avaliable with my current apache installation.

I found a patch that will give me that option http://pastebin.com/FnvUyjdJ, but have no ideia how to apply it. Could you guys help me?

Comment: What exact version of Ubuntu and Apache are you running. According to Ubuntu, this was fixed in version of 2.2.22 provided to Ubutnu 12.04 and 12.10 - http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-1627-1/

Comment: According with Apache website "Available in httpd 2.4.3 and later" if I put "SSLCompression off" and try to restart, I get an error. My Ubuntu is 12.04.1.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved with [a backported patch](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-1627-1/). You only need to update Apache to the version given in the security notice, or a later version.

Comment: I did `apt-get -u install apache2` and now none of my virtual hosts are accessible and no error is logged =O What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

This was provided by Ubuntu in the `precise-security` source in your /etc/apt/sources.list

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/2.2.22-1ubuntu1.2

Something like this

`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe`